# Updating a git pull request after a local rebase

Tags: git, github

I recently ran into a situation where my pull request for a bug fix got messed up when I rebase from upstream locally, and then tried to push to my local PR on github.
I wonder if I was going the right way, or that my workflow needs to be altered.

Basically, I followed this workflow:

- fork on github
- clone on local machine. Set origin (automatically) and upstream remotes.
- create `fix` branch.
- edit files.
- `git push -u origin fix` and submit a PR from this branch.
- in the mean time, one of the files in my fix got updated in the main repository. So I `git fetch upstream; git merge upstream/master`
- I update my origin/master: `git push`.
- I then `git rebase master` on my `fix` branch locally, manually merging them because of a conflict. `git add; git rebase --continue`.
- I then tried `git push` and that's where things went wrong. There doesn't seem to be a nice clean way to get that rebase `fix` branch into my PR.

So I wondered if I missed a step, or whether I should alter a step. I'm not sure if the `git push origin` was correct, or whether it needs to be more specific (e.g., with the branch name). Should/could I have tried something with `git push --force` in that last step (part of the PR was in my github repository, but very likely nowhere else pulled)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't introduce merges inside pull requests. The proper workflow is this:

- Fork
- Clone
- Branch
- [hardcore coding work]
- [commit(s)]
- Rebase (to upstream/master), e.g. using `git pull --rebase upstream master`
- Push
- Create a pull request.

That way you avoid merge commits and end up with clean commits in your pull request which are based on the current *master* of the upstream repository.

If you pushed before the rebase, you have to perform a forced push using `-f` to push again after rebasing since you rewrite history during the rebase.

Something worth to keep in mind: Merges (that are not fast-forward or rebases) should *never* occur in simple fix/feature branches - just like you should never rewrite history in your "main" branches which others might base own work on.

Comment: A side question: are you saying to never `git fetch upstream; git merge upstream/master` on my local repository? Because of the possible merge commits, and thus instead rebase? Normally, my master only follows upstream (and then pushes to origin) and nothing else happens there, so I guess in practice the merge and rebase turn out to be the same?

Comment: If you run this in your `master` branch it will always fast-forward - because you surely won't commit anything in master in a fork, right? Anyway, I did not include this for the sake of keeping it short. During actual development I do this from time to time: `git checkout master; git pull --ff-only upstream master; git push` - the pull combines fetch and merge.

Comment: What about when you need to make further changes following comments in the PR? Do you just accept that any further changes cannot be rebased to be part of the original commit and just commit and push them to update the PR?

Comment: You force push to the PR branch

Comment: @ChrisB now you can [squash](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-request-merge-squashing/) PR commits before merge. If more than one (clean and nice) commit need to be preserved in history, you polish them and force push as ThiefMaster noted. I think rewriting history in scope of an open PR is fine. Yes it wipes the commits and destroys the discussion somewhat, but I prefer clean Git log over integrity/readability of GitHub discussion.

Comment: I find [“Merge pull request” Considered Harmful](https://blog.spreedly.com/2014/06/24/merge-pull-request-considered-harmful) article related in that it is GitHub UI and workflow that pushes the not-so-picky users to produce all those nasty merge commits. Because it's so easy to "update" in one button click.

Answer (score 2):

> Should/could I have tried something with git push --force in that last step (part of the PR was in my github repository, but very likely nowhere else pulled)?

Yes. You need to force-push a branch if your local branch is not a descendant of the remote branch, which it is not after you rebased it.

*You should be aware of the consequences of a forced push though for other developers that may already have the overwritten changes, **I do not recommend it:*** Better use a simple pull to bring in the upstream changes.

Comment: I'd like to avoid `push -f` indeed. But how bad would it be on a branch created solely for a (small) PR that likely no-one else will clone? Since I'd expect most people will work of normal branches and not use someone elses PR to work from there. Though I can imagine a big PR that may get taken over by someone else at some point.

Comment: @Evert In case of a simple temporary branch with only one developer it may be feasible, but don't let it become something you consistently do.